# How to trace service firebird

Tags: delphi, monitoring, firebird, trace

How to trace all events for service firebird server with delphi xe10?
This is my code:

```
my := TIBControlService.Create(Self);

my.ServerName := '127.0.0.1/3050';
my.Protocol := TProtocol.TCP;

my.LoginPrompt := false;
my.TraceFlags := [tfQPrepare, tfQExecute, tfQFetch, tfError, tfStmt, tfConnect, tfTransact, tfBlob, tfService, tfMisc];

my.Params.Add( 'user_name=SYSDBA' );
my.Params.Add( 'password=masterkey' );

// -----
mh := MonitorHook;
mh.TraceFlags := my.TraceFlags;

Self.IBSQLMonitor1.TraceFlags := my.TraceFlags;
mh.RegisterMonitor(Self.IBSQLMonitor1);

Self.IBSQLMonitor1.Enabled := true;
Memo1.Lines.Add( Format('GetMonitorCount: %d',[mh.GetMonitorCount]) );


my.Attach;

Memo1.Lines.Add( Format('Active: %s',[System.StrUtils.IfThen(my.Active,'yes','no')]) );
```

and

```
procedure TForm1.IBSQLMonitor1SQL(EventText: string; EventTime: TDateTime);
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(EventText);
end;
```

Result:

```
GetMonitorCount: 1
Active: yes

[Application:]
:[Attach]

[Application:]
:[Query]
```

But this result is only from my application. When I connecting from another proces (ex.isql) my application not show this event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When talking about Interbase/Firebird the term **EVENT** has a very specific meaning, the specific SQL command that sends text constants to clients, who subscribed to those.

   See http://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-coding.html#fblangref25-psql-postevent

   However, the client should subscribe to the exactly the same text string, as posted by PSQL block. There were talks about enabling masks-based subscription, which would potentially made it possible to subscribe to all SQL events, like `*.*` matches all files in Windows, but for the best of my knowledge they never materialized.

   That is what "event" means in Firebird, but it does not seem that is what you mean, instead it looks you want to monitor all the kinds of activity flowing between the SQL server and all the applications, starting with SQL commands and more.

   If so, then there is no way to do it in general. You have to decide what exactly and why exactly do you want, and maybe there will be some **partial** solutions.
2. Firebird 2.5 introduced the so called *Trace API*, which allows you to subscribe to SOME of actions and be notified of them. This tends to introduce a significant load on the engine though, depending on how vague your subscription filters would be and how many requests the server receives - it might increase RAM and CPU usage up to total unusability.

   - The kinds of activity that can be subscribed for are limited. For example the process of reading BLOBs is not monitored. When I asked - I was struggling with the infamous "Invalid BLOB id" that was triggered by *Delphi dbExpress* library quirk - i was told that "no one ever needed this, and you have little reasons to need it too. You made a demo project, sent it to us - and we explained the behavior for you". THAT time having BLOBs access tracing would help me a lot, but to be objective, that was one and the only case I really needed it.
   - You might take a look at what you can get in general with *Firebird Trace Manager* - a CLI utility that is part of FB distribution, starting with 2.5.
   - You might take a look at *Firebird Profiler*, a free simplistic GUI tool from http://fbprofiler.sf.net
   - Commercial DB IDEs for Firebird, like IBExpert or UpScene TraceManager and probably others too, usually have Trace API support.
   - You may do your own implementation, using Trace API, starting with `Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\doc\README.trace_services.txt` and `Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\include\ibase.h`. It may also happen that 3rd party libraries like *Unified Interbase* or *IBObjects* have translated the API to Delphi. I think i saw something about trace in *UIB* but i am not sure. I would not expect though such a library to be part of *Delphi* distribution: from *Delphi* standpoint *Firebird* is direct competitor to their *Interbase* and *IBX* library would hardly have interest to diverge from their own *Interbase* by supporting *Firebird*-only functions.
3. Provided you only care about native applications like Delphi you might decide to make your own interposer **fbclient.dll** and install it on all the client computers instead of stock DLLs. Same for legacy-emulating **GDS32.DLL**, if used by your apps.

   - This DLL should totally provide all the API calls, both classic ones described in IB6 documentation at http://firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ with all the post-IB6 updates, and the new Firebird 3 "object oriented API".
   - It should log the calls in a way of your choosing, and then should proxy the call to the copy of original client DLL that you will hide for it with different file name. It should be installed instead of the standard client DLL on every computer you care to intercept and monitor.
   - It should not be very hard with the classic API, people were doing this, though did not publish. But the new ooAPI might be challenging.
   - It will only intercept applications, working through the *fbclient.DLL* interface. Java applications using **Jaybird** and C# applications using **.Net Provider** libraries would probably use underlying *wire protocol* skipping the *fbclient.dll* and thus your interposer too.

Comment: Your answer is helpful.  
Ad.1. You are right.  
Ad.2. The informations in this section are very interesting.  
Ad.3. It looks difficult
Thank you very much.